# Select data frame by dict passing in parameters or comprehension list python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to select rows in a dataframe passing a dict or a comprehension list.

I have a data frame with millions rows, I want to create a function to select just a part of this data frame corresponding to a list of parameters. To complexity it, I must pass the data frame and the list but this list can contain NaN values and '0'. So I must delete this entry to select the proper rows.

The entry list :

```
b = ['MUSTANG', 'Coupé', '0', np.nan, np.nan]

     AGE    KM     Brand   Model           Liter     Bodycar    Power
0    2.0  10000.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
1    2.0  10000.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
2    5.0  10400.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
3    5.0  10400.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
4   16.0  20700.0  FORD    MUSTANG          3.7        Coupé    317
5    7.0  23300.0  FORD    MUSTANG          3.7                 317
6    7.0  23300.0  FORD    MUSTANG          2.3        Coupé    301
7    7.0  23300.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0                 421
...

I started a function to remove the part of the list useless and try to select the proper rows but failed... 

  def func_mcclbp_incomp(df, mcclbp):
     ind = []

     mcclbp = [i if type(i) == str else '0' for i in mcclbp]
     ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(mcclbp) if x=='0']

     head = ['Brand','Model','Bodycar','Liter', 'Power']
     mmcclbp = {head[0]:mcclbp[0], head[1]:mcclbp[1], head[2]:mcclbp[2], \
             head[3]:mcclbp[3], head[4]:mcclbp[4]}
     for i in ind:
         del mmcclbp[head[i]]
     df = df[df[head[i]==mccblp[i]] for i in mmcclbp.key()]
     return df
```

I tried a comprehension list but pandas send me an error :

```
File "<ipython-input-235-6f78e45f59d4>", line 1
df = df[df[head[i].isin(mccblp[i]) for i in mmcclbp.keys()]]
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I tried passing a dict I have a KeyError.

The output needed if I use b is :

```
     AGE    KM     Brand   Model           Liter     Bodycar    Power
0    2.0  10000.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
1    2.0  10000.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
2    5.0  10400.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
3    5.0  10400.0  FORD    MUSTANG          5.0        Coupé    421
4   16.0  20700.0  FORD    MUSTANG          3.7        Coupé    317
6    7.0  23300.0  FORD    MUSTANG          2.3        Coupé    301
```

If I change b to another value like :

```
b = ['FORD', 'MUSTANG', 'Coupé', '3.7', '317']
```

The result will be :

```
     AGE    KM     Brand   Model           Liter     Bodycar    Power
4   16.0  20700.0  FORD    MUSTANG          3.7        Coupé    317
```

Someone knows how I can select list corresponding rows automatically ?

Thanks for you answer,

Chris.

Comment: Can you add desired output from `b = ['MUSTANG', 'Coupé', '0', np.nan, np.nan]` and your sample data?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to write the input... The edit shows you what I need to do.

Comment: Can you explain more first output - why get data if have `0` or `nan`s ?

Comment: The reason is just when a client send me a file, it can be possible that I don't have the all parameters or when the data is missing from the client they put a '0' value in it... So when I want to parse the file by categories I have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict` for filtering with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True` values per row for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).
Also is necessary convert all values of `DataFrame` to `string`s by `astype`, because all `values` of `dict` are `string`s too:

```
d = {'Brand':'FORD', 'Model':'MUSTANG', 'Bodycar':'Coupé', 'Liter':'3.7', 'Power':'317'}

print (df.astype(str)[list(d)] == pd.Series(d))
   Bodycar  Brand  Liter  Model  Power
0     True   True  False   True  False
1     True   True  False   True  False
2     True   True  False   True  False
3     True   True  False   True  False
4     True   True   True   True   True
6     True   True  False   True  False

mask = (df.astype(str)[list(d)] == pd.Series(d)).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
6    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
    AGE       KM Brand    Model  Liter Bodycar  Power
4  16.0  20700.0  FORD  MUSTANG    3.7   Coupé    317
```

Comment: Thanks again ! You too :)