# Create generic data filter on pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a generic filter on some data. Consider a boiled down example:

```
my_data = pd.DataFrame(some_data)
my_filter = {"value": 100, "direction": ">"}
```

now I want to leverage `numpy`'s `where` to do something like:

```
np.where(my_data (...) my_filter["value"])
```

where, as "(...)", I want `my_filter["direction"]`. Sure, I can use something like "`eval(...)`" by putting together an appropriate string.

**Question** But I was wondering if there is a way to do this without `eval(...)`?

**Follow-up on "already answered" claim:** The key here is that I need the *direction* to be generic. Sub-selecting data based on values is easy "`np.where(my_data == my_filter["value"])`", e.g.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data frame by dict passing in parameters or comprehension list python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241138/select-data-frame-by-dict-passing-in-parameters-or-comprehension-list-python-pan)

Comment: @AntonvBR it is very similar, but does it contain an explicit example of using the direction part? I see you have that in your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]:
   value direction
0    100         >
1     12         ^
2    101         >
3     13         v
4    100         <

In [74]: my_filter = ["value >= 100", "direction == '>'"]

In [75]: df.query(' and '.join(my_filter))
Out[75]:
   value direction
0    100         >
2    101         >
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you, using np.where i imagine something like this

```
df['filter'] = np.where((df['value'] == 100) & (df['direction'] == '>'), 1,0)

df.loc[df['filter'] == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example applied with your data from [Select data frame by dict passing in parameters or comprehension list python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241138/select-data-frame-by-dict-passing-in-parameters-or-comprehension-list-python-pan)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=[100,200],direction=['>','<']))
my_filter = {"value":100, "direction": ">"}

# Apply
mask = (df[list(my_filter)] == pd.Series(my_filter)).all(axis=1)
df[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator module.
Here is one example

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
my_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[1,1]])
my_filter = {"value": 1, "direction": operator.ge}
print(my_data.loc[my_filter["direction"](my_data[0],my_filter["value"])])
```

This should ideally do the job.
Otherwise you can use np.where with some modifications(personally I haven't used np.where much).